# "that's the least you did" vs "that's the last thing you did"

Tags: word-choice

I’m having some grammar issues, and I could really use some help.

How should it be

> You went to the grocery store to buy limes but that's the least you did
>
> You went to the grocery store to buy limes but that’s the last thing you did

Meaning: the person went to the grocery store and bought different food items but limes.

Comment: What are you actually asking? Both of those sentences are grammatical. I also can't follow the meaning of the sentence after (ironically) *meaning*.

Answer (score 0):

Neither one really conveys what you are trying to convey.

The first, "went to the grocery store to buy limes, but that's the least you did" implies that you did more than just go to the grocery store, or that you did something else other than just buying things (e.g. cleaned the store).

The second implies that you have done nothing since buying limes at the grocery store.

What you are looking for is something like this: "You went to the grocery store to buy limes, but that's not all you bought"

If you want to convey that they went for limes but came back with other things, but no limes, then  that would be "You went to the grocery store to buy limes, but you came back with other things instead."